# Dereferencing iterators to int and int& in C++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
vector<int> v={1,2,4};
int &a=*v.begin();
cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code segment, the dereferenced value of the iterator `v.begin()` assigned to `&a`. Printing `a` displays 1

```
int main()
{
vector<int> v={1,2,4};
int a=*v.begin();
cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the iterator is deferenced and the value is assigned to `a` (without the &) instead. Printing `a` still displays 1.

I'm still learning C++ and it doesn't make sense to me why the first code block works. What does `int &a` signify?

Comment: You seem to be asking what a _reference variable_ is.

Comment: References are a fundamental concept in C++. I don't want to discourage you from writing small programs to test things out, but when something is so fundamental as a reference, you really should be studying a book or tutorial. You aren't going to learn what they are by experimentation. (or by asking on Stack Overflow).

Comment: I'd also take issue with the notion that you are "assigning iterators" to anything. You dereference the iterator before you assign anything anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int& a = *v.begin();` makes `a` a reference to the first element in the vector so anything you do to that reference is reflected upon the referenced element. Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 4};
    int &a = *v.begin();
    a = 100;
    std::cout << v[0]; // prints 100
}
```

If you instead do `int a = *v.begin();` you *copy* the value held by `v[0]` into `a` and `v[0]` and `a` live their separate lifes:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 4};
    int a = *v.begin();
    a = 100;
    std::cout << v[0]; // prints 1
}
```